# 'PostgreSQL' component is not operational in Work Fusion RPA Express

Tags: postgresql

I have installed Work Fusion RPA express. No issues during installation. 
Recorded series of action, But cannot play any recording in RPA Recorder.

Then:
I checked the Platform Monitor and found 'PostgreSQL' component is not operational. 
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Instead of recording like a video, use 'Create New Recording' option (shortcut is F5) under File->New. Once you click on this option, a new window will pop-up with a default name and file extension as .rpae. Keep the extension as it is and you can change the filename. Add actions from action library using drag-and-drop. For more: visit the official knowledge base i.e. https://kb.workfusion.com/display/RPAe/How+to+Use+RPA+Recorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check that your port 15423 is open
- Check Firewall inbound rules (Firewall → Advanced settings). It should be enabled for RPAExpress Postgres

If this does not help, create a post on https://forum.workfusion.com